# How to programmatically adjust the height of a cell in a TableView if everything is created programmatically, without using a storyboard?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, heightforrowatindexpath

I've looked at a lot of examples, but somehow they don't work.
My Code Below.
Objects constraints in a custom cell:

[image]

Below is the code in the class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
}
```

//tableview ->

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 340
}
```

Comment: what is problem?

Comment: set height in heightForRowAt that is set height of cell.

Comment: Please add your code as a code and not as an image

Comment: HI Sagar! I want to create a dynamic cell. The height of the cell should change depending on the amount of text in the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of things worth addressing:

#### 1. Do not setup your layout in `layoutSubviews()`

This method will get triggered multiple times everytime there has been a change to the layout made, meaning all of these constraints will be duplicated, and will eventually cause problems. Try to set them in `init` of the cell.

#### 2. Do not implement `heightForRowAt`

When implementing this function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 340
}
```

you are telling tableview to give the cell this exact size. According to documentation:

> The value returned by this method takes precedence over the value in the rowHeight property.

Remove this code!

#### 3. Set `rowHeight` to automatic size value

You have already correctly set the `estimatedRowHeight` value, but we are going to also need the `rowHeight` property to be set to `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

```swift
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

And now you should be good to go!

#### Bonus: Scrolling Performance improvements

Table view will benefit from any additional information on the size of the cells and you can supply that information with `estimatedHeightForRowAt` if you are able to calculate a better approximate than the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` value you have set in the initial setup.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // return more accurate value here
}
```

Comment: It works 100% Thanks a lot!!!
I moved all the constraints to the initialization of the cell, it helped.

Comment: glad to hear that!